# Appending queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

A quick technical question-

I have two queries that output some of the same data. For example, lets say that both queries have column X and Y, and each one has one row with some data in each column. So, we have cell X1 and cell Y1 in each query.

How would I go about appending the two queries such that there are still two columns, X and Y, but two rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use `UNION`

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html
(Its supported on Access also)

Answer (score 4):

you can use UNION, but remember the number of column must be the same:

```
mysql> select * from test_big;
+-------------+
| id          |
+-------------+
|          10 |
|          11 |
|   123456789 |
|  1234567890 |
| 12345678901 |
+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  0 | a    |
|  2 | 3    |
|  3 | none |
|  6 |      |
|  9 | a    |
| 11 | a    |
| 50 | a    |
+----+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_big union select * from test;;
ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
ERROR: 
No query specified
```

but you can fix it using the same number of columns

```
mysql> select * from test_big union select id from test;
+-------------+
| id          |
+-------------+
|          10 |
|          11 |
|   123456789 |
|  1234567890 |
| 12345678901 |
|           0 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
|           6 |
|           9 |
|          50 |
+-------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Your first query]

UNION

[Your second query]
```